# laravel 5.5 blade throws broken html as output sometimes

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade

**Expected Output(show most of the time)**

```
<li class="m-menu__item  m-menu__item--active " aria-haspopup="true"  data-menu-submenu-toggle="hover">
        <a  href="http://127.0.0.1:8000/invoices" class="m-menu__link m-menu__toggle">
            <i class="m-menu__link-icon flaticon-clipboard"></i>
            <span class="m-menu__link-text">
                Invoices
            </span>
        </a>
    </li>
```

**Broken Html(sometimes throws output with broken tags)**

```
<li class="m-menu__item  m-menu__item--active " aria-haspopup="true"  data-menu-submenu-toggle="hover">
            <a  href="http://127.0.0.1:8000/invoices" class="m-menu__link m-menu__toggle">
                <i class="m-menu__link-icon flaticon-clipboard"></i>
                <s                </span>
            </a>
        </li>
```

**blade code**

```
<li class="m-menu__item @if(isset($sidebar) && $sidebar == 'invoice') m-menu__item--active @endif" aria-haspopup="true"  data-menu-submenu-toggle="hover">
        <a  href="{{ asset('invoices') }}" class="m-menu__link m-menu__toggle">
            <i class="m-menu__link-icon flaticon-clipboard"></i>
            <span class="m-menu__link-text">
                Invoices
            </span>
        </a>
    </li>
```

tried enabling errors, logging disabling cache but still no luck
is there some error in blade rendering

Comment: There's nothing wrong here, the error must be elsewhere

Comment: This is one of case getting similar broken tags throughout the app, i have been using laravel for last 4 years

Answer (score 0):

Try to improve your code, but may not fix the bug.

```html
<li class="m-menu__item {{ isset($sidebar) && $sidebar == 'invoice' ? 'm-menu__item--active' : '' }}" aria-haspopup="true"  data-menu-submenu-toggle="hover">
    <a  href="{{ url('/invoices') }}" class="m-menu__link m-menu__toggle">
        <i class="m-menu__link-icon flaticon-clipboard"></i>
        <span class="m-menu__link-text">
            Invoices
        </span>
    </a>
</li>
```

use `asset()` function only to load asset files (JS, CSS, images)

use `url('uri')` on anchor or `route('route-name')` even better